# How to split text at first dash and at underscore using regex

Tags: regex, vba

I have the following as separate inputs:

```
MCMASTER - 94510A260_M8 EXPAND INSERT FOR PLASTICS
MISUMI-AIPOK6-20
MISUMI - AIPOK6-20
J-5858-01_MISUMI-AIPOK6-20
J-5858-01_MISUMI - AIPOK6-20
J-XXXX_MISUMI-AIPOK6-20
J-5858_MISUMI - AIPOK6-20
```

I need to split each line to get vendor, part number and description.

I am using:

```
(J-\d{4}-\d{2}\D{0,1}_|J-XXXX-\d{2}\D{0,1}_|J-\d{4}_){0,1}(.*?)-(.*)_{0,1}(.*)
```

as pattern but it does not work on first line of input (starting with MCMASTER.) It works on all the rest.

I expect to get something like this for first input:

```
Group#1 "Undefined"
Group#2 MCMASTER
Group#3 94510A260
Group#4 M8 EXPAND INSERT FOR PLASTICS
```

Comment: What is the required pattern, i.e `contain 3 uppercase letter and some letters`?

Comment: Job number - Vendor - Part number - Description

Comment: Currenty, I am getting:

Group#1: "Undefined"
Group#2: MCMASTER
Group#3: 94510A260_M8 EXPAND INSERT FOR PLASTICS
Group#4: Empty

Comment: it looks like this one works:
(J-\d{4}-\d{2}\D{0,1}_|J-XXXX-\d{2}\D{0,1}_|J-\d{4}_){0,1}(.*?)-([^_]*)_{0,1}(.*)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this:

```
(J-(?:\d{4}|XXXX)\D?(?:-\d{2})?_)?(.*?)-([^_\n\r]*)_?(.*)
```

See here: https://regex101.com/r/yljBDA/1

I replaced all your `{0,1}` with the shorter `?` and also condensed your first capturing group a bit with use of some non-capturing groups.

I can tell you `(.*)_{0,1}(.*)` on the text `94510A260_M8 EXPAND INSERT FOR PLASTICS` wouldn't have the desired effect because `.*` is greedy; that is, it captures as much as it can. My initial instinct was to make the first capture non-greedy with `.*?` but that didn't work for some reason. So I just faked it by using a negating character class `[^_\n\r]*`. If you're working on this input line by line, you should be able to shorten that down to just `[^_]`.